# Get colour of an SVG gradient and use it as a SASS variable?

Tags: css, svg, sass

I have been trying to figure out if it is at all possible in order to take an SVG asset. Go to its file path. Access its color or fill and use that specific colour as a SASS variable.

I have been looking at [this stackoveflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051351/svg-gradient-using-css) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123953/svg-fill-url-behaving-strangely-in-firefox) one as well. But they seem to be targeting a specific SVG and not actually using it in the way I was hoping. Unless there is something I am missing.

So basically I want to go:

```
background: url(../../../asset/button.svg/#gradient);
```

or be able to go and store it in a SASS variable like:

```
$myGradient: url(../../../asset/button.svg/#gradient);
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Basically...no, you can't.

Comment: This is saddening. Thanks for the input

Comment: You would have to parse it as a text file, find the fill attribute and then output that to a file and then import that file with SASS. No idea how you would actually do that though.

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you are after, but if you want to use an [SVGGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients) as a background-image for some HTML element, you'll have to place in your svg document a rect filled with this gradient, in CSS point to your whole svg document (`url(yourfile.svg)`) and then adjust your background-size. If you want to use some gradient defined in an svg document as the fill rule for an svg element in your current document, you will have to change your url to `url(yourFile.svg#theIdOfYourGradient)`.

Comment: Yea it looks like ill be heading in that route!

Comment: maybe related https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107264/convert-svg-linear-gradient-to-css-linear-gradient-adobe-xd , @josephus-paye