# SVG styling <use> (fill x% of the content with linearGradient)

Tags: svg

I have an icon that I want to use many times on my page.
I want the icon to be filled dynamically (how much of it will be filled) from server data.

what I got so far is this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="myWarningId" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 27.8 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 27.8 24;" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 27.8 24" y="0px" x="0px" id="warning" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <style type="text/css">
            #myWarningId .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
            #myWarningId polygon{fill: inherit;}
        </style>
        <linearGradient id="half" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="red" />
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="blue" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue" />
        </linearGradient>
        <g>
            <polygon points="13.9,0 0,24 27.8,24"></polygon>
            <g>
                <path d="m13.9,16.1l0,0c-1.1,0 -2.1,-0.9 -2.1,-2.1l0,-4.9c0,-1.1 0.9,-2.1 2.1,-2.1l0,0c1.1,0 2.1,0.9 2.1,2.1l0,4.9c-0.1,1.2 -1,2.1 -2.1,2.1z" class="st1"></path>
                <circle r="1.7" cy="19.5" cx="13.9" class="st1"></circle>
            </g>
        </g>
    </symbol>
</defs>
<g class="layer">
    <!-- this use will be generated multiple times -->
    <use x="0" y="0" fill="url(#half)"  transform="matrix(0.20000000298023224,0,0,0.20000000298023224,0,0) " xlink:href="#warning" id="svg_2"></use>
</g>
```

Now, if I want to change where the line is I need to do it in the `<def>` tag. but this is changing all my `<use>` elements.

how can I change the % of the fill for each `<use>` dynamically and individually?

I don't think that making 100 `<linearGradient>` definitions for each precent and changing the fillUrl would be a good practice...

Comment: Don't use use elements at all, they exist to show the same thing multiple times. Simply draw whatever you want in each different way.

Comment: let's say I have to... the svg is not generated by me at all. All I can do is ask that it will be generated by some kind of format

Comment: @RobertLongson I think you meant symbols, not elements.

Comment: @Waruyama, I meant what I said, the word use is repeated. I.e. Don't use <use> elements....

Comment: @Dzak use one <use> element per thing being displayed, which is pretty inefficient but would work I suppose.

Comment: @RobertLongson for my understanding (a couple of hours of reading), if I want to display icon many times, it is more efficient to define it once and use it as much as you want with the <use> element. I would like to know why you think this is inefficient so I could point it out to my co-workers.

Comment: That's true but if you use it many times, you'll get copies of that thing you're using many times and you don't want that because each of your instances is different. <use> is only useful if you're using the **same** thing many times.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put the gradient into the symbol if you want to change the percentage of the stop. If you are fine with steps (10%, 20%, 30%), you can implement one gradient for each step. It looks like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="myWarningId" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 27.8 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 27.8 24;" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="_10" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="red" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="_20" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="red" />
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="_30" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="red" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 27.8 24" y="0px" x="0px" id="warning" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <style type="text/css">
            #myWarningId .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
            #myWarningId polygon{fill: inherit;}
        </style>
        <g>
            <polygon points="13.9,0 0,24 27.8,24"></polygon>
            <g>
                <path d="m13.9,16.1l0,0c-1.1,0 -2.1,-0.9 -2.1,-2.1l0,-4.9c0,-1.1 0.9,-2.1 2.1,-2.1l0,0c1.1,0 2.1,0.9 2.1,2.1l0,4.9c-0.1,1.2 -1,2.1 -2.1,2.1z" class="st1"></path>
                <circle r="1.7" cy="19.5" cx="13.9" class="st1"></circle>
            </g>
        </g>
    </symbol>
</defs>

<g class="layer">
    <!-- this use will be generated multiple times -->
    <use x="0" y="0" fill="url(#_10)" transform="matrix(0.20000000298023224,0,0,0.20000000298023224,0,0) " xlink:href="#warning" id="svg_1"></use>
    <use x="0" y="32" fill="url(#_20)" transform="matrix(0.20000000298023224,0,0,0.20000000298023224,0,0) " xlink:href="#warning" id="svg_2"></use>
    <use x="0" y="64" fill="url(#_30)" transform="matrix(0.20000000298023224,0,0,0.20000000298023224,0,0) " xlink:href="#warning" id="svg_3"></use>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I was afraid this would be the only answer for me... but what is the difference if I put it inside the symbol tag or in the def?

Comment: If you you want the gradient to be used by different symbols, it just makes sense to put it outside the symbol.

Comment: didn't check yet. but thanks for pointing it out. and yes, in my case this style should be relevant only for this symbol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123953/svg-fill-url-behaving-strangely-in-firefox may help for the firefox problem

Comment: can I chage the fill attribute on the `<use>` element to a css class?